# move files to newly created current date folder using powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

```
enter code here
$rootpath = "D:\SSIS_Package_Deployments\"
$e = "ssisname"
$m = "\"
$de = New-Item $rootpath$e$m"Deployment_$((get-date).toString('yyyyMMdd'))" -type directory
#if (-not {$de | out-null}){
   if ( $de ){
      foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem -Path $de -type directory)
      {

         if (($i.Name -match "Deployment_$((get-date).toString('yyyyMMdd'))") )
         {
            echo $i.Name
            Move-Item c:\temp\STA\*.dtsConfig $i.Name -force
         }
      } 
   }
```

script having newly created current date folders but files are not moving in that folder
it gives error item already exists and I want to add file in that folder

Comment: 5th line should be
`$de = New-Item "$rootpath$e$mDeployment_$((get-date).toString('yyyyMMdd'))" -type directory`

Comment: still facing error:=> problem New-Item : Item with specified name D:\SSIS_Package_Deployments\ssisname20130610 already exists.
At line:6 char:23
+    if ( $de = New-Item <<<<  "$rootpath$e$mDeployment_$((get-date).toString('yyyyMMdd'))" -type directory ){
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (D:\SSIS_Package...sisname20130610:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand